# how to call main activity within PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

i have main activity in which i have Four menus. and i have one SipSetting class which extends PreferenceActivity in which i have four fields.now when i am in this SipSetting class, On clicking on menu button menu does not popups? how to open that menu within this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)` in every `Activity` and inflate appropriate menu there. This menu could be shared among different activities, i.e. you may inflate same menu for several activities. Remember, that you would also need to override `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)` in every `Activity`.

Is that what you asked about?

Comment: yeah , but my all other class can extend the Activity so there is a no need to define menu for each of that classes but in the case of SipSetting class which is regarding Preferences so it must extend the PreferenceActivity. so how to use that menu in this class?

Comment: whatever task are done with the menuitem the same task i want to do in this preference file.so if i override the onoptioncreatemenu() method then it is just show me the menu but how it will do the task of main menu?

Comment: as I described: override `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)`, inflate menu, and override `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)`.

You may also try this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116588/re-using-options-menu-code/8118540#8118540

Comment: in your link can you explain this line (R.menu.gv_options_menu,menu) i am not getting this menu. should i create seperate xml for menus?

Comment: `gv_options_menu` is just a name of menu resource, i.e. the question-starter has his/her menu defined in `gv_options_menu.xml` file. The second `Menu` argument which you pass to `inflate(int menuRes, Menu menu)` you receive in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method.