# Inheritance - onCreateOptionsMenu (with super call)

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I have a BaseActivity class that extends Activity, in it I have

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // draw menu stuff
    }
```

Then I have other class that extend BaseActivity, such as

> HelpActivity extends Activity

I thought that according to the rules of inheritance, it would automatically inherit BaseActivty's onCreateOptionMenu call.  It doesn't, so I'm not sure why.

But anyway, in HelpActivity I added this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

and THAT didn't work either (ie no menu was displayed on Galaxy Nexus). So I literally copied and pasted BaseActivity's onCreateOptionsMenu call into HelpActivity, and that worked. Why is this the case?

edit: 
Two notes:
When I say it's not working, I mean: I have a Galaxy Nexus, and the Menu doesn't even get displayed on the ActionBar (ActionBarSherlock).  When it works, I get the menu, including the menu ellipsis.

Secondly:

According to the Android docs:

> Tip: If your application contains multiple activities and some of them
>   provide the same Options Menu, consider creating an activity that
>   implements nothing except the onCreateOptionsMenu() and
>   onOptionsItemSelected() methods. Then extend this class for each
>   activity that should share the same Options Menu. This way, you have
>   to manage only one set of code for handling menu actions and each
>   descendant class inherits the menu behaviors.

Got this from: [Re-using Options menu code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116588/re-using-options-menu-code?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you have pasted your `HelpActivity` is not extending `BaseActivity`.
`HelpActivity extends Activity`

Comment: My God, that class is about 1200 lines long, I hit ctrl+z and it reverted the extend call. Definite egg on the face moment.